# Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dummy@.books.id' in 'where clause'

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm having some trouble finding out where I'm getting this error from:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dummy@.books.id' in 'where clause'

sql query

```
UPDATE 
    `dummy@`.`books` 
SET 
    `isbn` = '1234532', 
    `title` = 'cakephp blog tutorial', 
    `id` = 5, 
    `description` = 'gh', 
    `author_name` = 'andrew' 
WHERE 
    `dummy@.books.id` = '5'
```

if i edit the record the following error has occurred

controller function

```
function edit ($id = NULL){
         if (!$id && empty($this->request->data)) {
          $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Book', true);
          $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
       }  

        else {    
            $this->Book->create();

         $save = $this->Book->save($this->request->data);
            if($save){ 

               $this->Session->setFlash('book detail edit successfully');
               $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index',$id));
              } 
       }
           if(empty($this->request->data)){               
           $this->request->data = $this->Book->read(NULL,$id);
        }           
   }
```

and  view ctp file

```
<?php  echo $this->Form->create('Book');?>
<fieldset>
    <legend> Edit New Book </legend>
    <?php

    echo $this->Form->input('isbn');
    echo $this->Form->input('title');
    echo $this->Form->hidden('id'); 
    echo $this->Form->input('description');
    echo $this->Form->input('author_name');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Edit Book');?>
```

Comment: show your Book model code please - the rest of it isn't relevant

Comment: in model file nothing has written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check your database config

The string `dummy@` is supposed to be the name of the database to connect to.

Check that the `database.php` file is configured to connect to a valid database (refer to the [default database.php file](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/database.php.default) if in doubt), it should look something like this:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'database_name', // <- "dummy@" ?
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

Comment: in config file, database name is correct..but can't find out the error